# Endless loop emptying an account with Contact Creations

Tags: go-ethereum

I made various things with Ethereum and I probably left something strange: now, as soon as I add ether to the account `0x22e1472e3486dd72f4d65e1f6ca7b2f49205fc26` it is emptied automatically with Contact Creations (with an empty contract).

You can see it [with any explorer](http://etherscan.io/address/0x22e1472e3486dd72f4d65e1f6ca7b2f49205fc26). Here is my last attempt, as seen by Etherscan:

```
0x07b541ef53a5aa2d3e22cd8bc1a8cb4e2f982be0f76ed8f96dc7774de834cc84  1793620 22 secs ago 0x22e1472e3486dd72f4d65e1f6ca7b2f49205fc26  [Send]   Contract Creation  0 Ether 0.04400132
0x797986800b4a66516f675387952eab5e87be051b38019b6ac55216b4dcb1c6a4  1793620 22 secs ago 0x22e1472e3486dd72f4d65e1f6ca7b2f49205fc26  [Send]   Contract Creation  0 Ether 0.04400132
0xa63c1ce1d68c31e84f2107a5a5c6e936f0cfc45490e00676d675030ec931d5be  1793618 38 secs ago 0xc90cd1fa9940a4d4a07a37c53bb4f423fd286945  [Receive]   0x22e1472e3486dd72f4d65e1f6ca7b2f49205fc26  0.1 Ether   0.00042
```

When the account is empty, contract creation of course stops, and resumes a few seconds after I add ethers. I tried:

- restarting geth
- running geth with `--cache "0"`
- checking with ps that no program was running on my machine, sending requests
- it does not come from RPC, since it is not enabled

None of these changed anything.

The contract creations have stable characteristics: 2300000 gas units, empty contract, data `0x5b620186a05a131560135760016020526000565b600080601f600039601f565b6000f3` But I don't know how to use these to investigate.

So, I certainly made a stupid mistake but my question is *which one*? How to investigate such a problem? Where is the ghost?

```
% geth version 
Geth
Version: 1.4.8-stable
Protocol Versions: [63 62 61]
Network Id: 1
Go Version: go1.6.2
OS: linux
GOPATH=
GOROOT=/usr/lib/go-1.6
```

Comment: I think you should talk to the geth developers about this.

Comment: Done, see https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/2764

Comment: It is unlikely anyone would send ether to this address to test it. However I also think that you have described what you see, but have provided no information about if your address is a contract in itself or the code that you might have implemented. Also note that you are on the soft fork version of Geth. You might want to think about rolling back.

Comment: I never suggested to send ethers to this address. Also, as you can see on any explorer, it is an account, not a contract.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SteveTalk, in the [Github issue](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/2764#issuecomment-231584482) found a very likely cause (because he ran on the same problem): it seems it was a consequence of the [advice given by Slock.it](https://blog.slock.it/dao-security-advisory-live-updates-2a0a42a2d07b#.i3x8wu31c) during the attack against The DAO. The code suggested by Slock.it is buggy and can leave unprocessed transactions, ready to be executed as soon as there are ethers to eat.

Next time, do not execute code from Slock.it before thinking.